# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Tridion's [first moderator election](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Dominic Cronin]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Bart Koopman who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5890718230904832/0).

Comment: Welcome to the mod gang Dominic!

Comment: Thanks, @Bart for your time as a mod!

Congrats and welcome, @Dom!